# Read sdcard data through Wifi

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-sdcard, android-wireless

I am trying to read data from Sdcard through Wifi. I have connected to the device through Wifi already. How can I access the Sdcard and read files inside the Sdcard?
Any sample code available?
Thanks

Comment: could you post your code ?

Comment: I am still searching how to code. I like to have some clues. if possible :)

Comment: I can find Android App like "Wireless card reader". But I like to merge the code into my app.Thanks

Comment: I found good reference at http://rorist.github.io/android-network-discovery/. I'll try first and will provide solution later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes [this link](http://rorist.github.io/android-network-discovery/) is the solution for me. Now I could manage to read text files from the external SDcard through Wifi. Thanks those developers who develop this Network Discovery app.